# How can I Update Defect Owner via versionone Rest api

Tags: api, rest, versionone

I'm trying to update the owner of a defect through the api.  I can update all the other fields I need, except the Owners field is not updating.  The response returned from the call is 200 'OK', but the value is not being updated.

The attribute section of the xml payload looks like this:

```
<Attribute name='Owners' act='add'><![CDATA[Member:2904]]></Attribute>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how I should be formatting the call to update the owner of a defect.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

do the next please

Post to:

```
  <Server Base URI>/rest-1.v1/Data/Defect/<YourDefectID>
  Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
```

Payload body:

```
  <Asset>
     <Relation name="Owners">
       <Asset idref="Member:2904" act="add"/>     
     </Relation>    
   </Asset>
```

In that particular case you are trying to update a multi-value relationship that's why it has to be done differently.
For more information you can check

https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Recipes/Update_an_Asset